# How to do a load image like Google Maps?

Tags: android

I am researching about how to do a load start image like google maps. For example when I click in my Google Maps apk, show me the next image:

[image]

How can I do something similar in my app?
I think, I'm searching so bad because is something common, but I dont find anything about that.

Comment: It's called a splash screen

Comment: @Sermanes Its a splash screen

Comment: Ohhhh thanks sorry I thought was a special activity or load activity or something similar. Thank you so much. @Nisarg and TimCastelijns

Comment: @Sermanes No problem.